# How to pull values from properties file into persistence.xml and context.xml?

Tags: java, maven, properties-file, persistence.xml, context.xml

I have an app with Java 17, Tomcat 10.

I would like to use a properties file (or its variation) so I can read it from different sides of my code or from my `persistence.xml` and `context.xml` files.

**What have I tried?**

I created a properties file and imported it into a listener.
I also managed it by putting in the `catalina.properties` a `app.profile=profile`

This worked in a Java class, but for the `context.xml` and `persistence.xml` it doesn't read the properties.

I have created profiles in the pom.xml with the properties.
But in the `persistence.xml` and `context.xml` I can't extract the properties.
I followed advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661290/how-to-get-my-applicationcontext-xml-file-pull-a-value-from-a-properties-file).